# Iterate in Python with a loop until the end of the list is reached

Tags: python, for-loop, loops

I am working on a project where I want to pull long lists of data from an API (Strava) and put them in a MySQL database (not shown in code). There are some limitations to the API and they don't allow to pull more than 200 records per request. Therefore, I need to find a way to iterate over the results, but to stop when the end of the list is reached (It never returns completely empty and does not error out either, no matter how many pages I pull).

So, I defined a function that pulls the data from the API and the first key in the JSON output is the effort_count which equals the number of entries in the list. I try to use that number from the function in the loop that I built to iterate over the list using the function.

```
import urllib2
import json 

strava_api='xxxxxxx'
def strava(segment_id,page,per_page):

    access_token = strava_api
    url='https://www.strava.com/api/v3/segments/' + str(segment_id) +'/leaderboard' +'?&access_token=' + access_token       

    final_url=url + "&page=" + str(page) + "&per_page=" + str(per_page)
    json_obj=urllib2.urlopen(final_url)

    data = json.load(json_obj) 
    effort_count=data['effort_count']

counter = 1
max_page = effort_count/200+1
for counter in range (1,max_page):
    strava(894142,counter,200) # 894142 is an existing segment and 200 is the max number of records displayed
    counter = counter + 1
```

However, when I run this, I get the error that 'effort_count' is not defined. Is this because it is not possible to use a variable from a function in this loop? Is there a workaround?

ps I am quite new at coding, so it is very well possible I am taking the wrong approach entirely.

Comment: It's because variables defined in a function are local to that function.

Comment: efforts_count is local to strava function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed `effort_count` is not defined at the global scope.

You could remedy this by declaring it `global` at the start of your method e.g.

```
def strava(segment_id,page,per_page):
    global effort_count

    access_token = strava_api
```

But you're still left with the problem that `effort_count` is accessed before your method is invoked.

You should also initialise it to some sensible default value at the start of your script.

Comment: Thanks Robert! That actually works. Before the strava function I define a global variable effort_count, then set it too 300 and in the function it's redefined to whatever comes from the API! (probably not really beatiful coding, but it works!)

Comment: Cool. You can go ahead and mark my answer as the correct one so :) Maybe even give it an upvote!

Comment: hmmm, cheered too soon, thought it was doing what I wanted, but because I set it to 300 before the function it stays 300 throughout the rest of the script. I thought it changed in the function, but it does not. When I set it as global in the function I get error global name is not defined. I will dig on!

Comment: you also need to set `global effort_count` at the start of `strava` as in my example ...

Comment: You are right! I had to fiddle around a little and read your comments better :-)